# Article help: Is it "I worked as A [X]" or "I worked as THE [X]"?

Tags: articles

What is the correct article to use in this sentence? (Is it "a" or "the"?) I can't seem to figure out which sentence is right.

> I worked as **a** one-person marketing team for a PR company.

Or

> I worked as **the** one-person marketing team for a PR company.

Thoughts? For context, I'm writing up a professional bio.

Comment: Neither is incorrect; the definite article sounds more forceful, conveys more authority.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Looking at the sentences now, I wonder. Could using the definite article imply that there are more one-person teams in the company? e.g. I worked as the one-person marketing team, and there was a one-person editing team and a one-person tech team too?

Comment: I worked as **a (= as an example of a)** one-person marketing team for a PR company. -- “**the**” is a demonstrative adjective: It adds “**that we are aware of**” or “**that has been defined**” to its noun --- I worked as **the** one-person marketing team [**that is defined as being**] for a PR company. You will note that because the position is defined, it is specific. This means that there will not be any other **one-person marketing teams *for that company.***

Comment: Yes (obviously your bolding above is to highlight the article, but "I worked as the one-person _marketing team_ for a PR company" could stand in contrast to the one-person financial team, the one-person entertainments team ... (your examples are better). But I still feel that use of the indefinite article here comes over as being rather weak. Opinion, though. The default sense is the one you intend.

Comment: @Greybeard Apologies, but I'm a bit confused. Does that mean that you prefer to use the definite article in this case?

I only want to convey that there was one marketing team, and it happened to be a team of one.

Comment: @AranYarne My comment was more "in addition to" Edwin A's. I agree with him.